# How to make a list of videos in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to create a list of videos for PageView.builder,how to do this?
and after what should I do with this part of the code:

```
 void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.asset('assets/vod_1.mp4')


      ..initialize().then((value) {
        _controller.play();
        _controller.setLooping(true);

        
        setState(() {});
      });
  }
```

and this:

````
 return PageView.builder(

          onPageChanged: (index) {

            setState(() {
              _controller.seekTo(Duration.zero);
              _controller.play();



            });

          },```
````

Comment: Sorry, but we have not idea what you "should do" with your code, we don't know the context or the requirements. Why don't you tell us what you want to do, show us what you did so far and where exactly you are stuck?

Comment: please share your code properly to get better answer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.